# Pixels in CSS vs pixel density

Tags: html, css

I am incredibly new to HTML and CSS and it just occurred to me that when deciding something is 5px say, since a pixel's physical size is dependent on the density then surely 5px on a screen of 100 ppi would look bigger than on a screen of 300 ppi.

Is this correct and if so is there any way to mediate this?

Comment: Why do you need to "mediate" this in the first place? Maybe you may want to use `em` and `%`?

Answer (score 6):

Absolutely!  Typically on a desktop, 1 css pixel = 1 pixel.  Mobile devices (especially with newer high-res displays) have caused us some headaches.  Here's my favourite workaround:

```
(function() {
    var meta = document.createElement("meta");
    meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
    var content = 'initial-scale=';
    content += 1 / window.devicePixelRatio;
    content += ',user-scalable=no';
    meta.setAttribute('content', content);
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(meta);
})();
```

I typically add this as the first child of my body tag, but it should probably be in the head tag.  This script modifies a device's scale such based on the pixel density of the display and forces 1 CSS pixel to equal 1 pixel.

Enjoy!

Comment: Thanks - I'm sure it works but to be honest at my stage that doesn't really mean much! Would another way be just to use mm, cm, etc or %'s?

Comment: You can always use em.  I find that's a useful unit that accounts for different resolutions and user preferences.  Good rule of thumb is 1 em = 16px (or 1 em = 16pt).  I've made a lot of websites and mobile sites/apps using em to determine the size of divs, font, etc.

Comment: Pixels and % for CSS. Metrics such as inches and cm are good for printable documents.

Comment: To expand on that, inches and cm are great in CSS for printed media. CSS isn't only for the screen.

Comment: Too bad this no longer works with notebooks either -- my Thinkpad has a physical density closer to 178dpi, but window.devicePixelRatio returns 1 on both Chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

A CSS pixel is not a physical pixel!
96 CSS px ~= 1 physical inch.
refer to https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/

Answer (score -1):

You can also use `@media` queries which allows you to use different `css` for different sized screens:

You can learn more [CSS Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

```
@media all and (max-width: 699px) and (min-width: 520px), (min-width: 1151px) {
  body {
    background: #ccc;
  }
}
```

Another screen size

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) and (min-width: 700px) {
  #sidebar ul li a:before {
    content: "Email: ";
    font-style: italic;
    color: #666;
  }
}
```