# How to use CSS with physical pixel dimensions?

Tags: html, css

I am interested in using a web browser for an LED wall installation.  LED walls have extremely precise requirements (to avoid tearing) for placement of objects with physical pixels.

Reading questions and answers [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15687276/pixels-in-css-vs-pixel-density) I become nervous when I read sentences such as:

> Typically on a desktop, 1 css pixel = 1 pixel

Is the workaround in that answer (from 2013) still required to make sure that when I set something such as

```
p {
    position: absolute;
    left: 4px;
}
```

That 4px means four physical pixels *on all browsers and displays*?

Is there a more modern way?

Comment: The think what you actually mean reffers to mobile devices. The thing is a hardware problem. On mobile devices you have more physical (real) pixels then you actually can address.  for example a device has 1440x2560px. However those are super pixels while the device actually has only 360x640px that can be addressed by the software. The developer just uses superpixels for getting a sharper image. YOu cant adress those pixels. The manufacturer decides the ratio, its different for every device.

Comment: There are a vw and vh which is viewport width and viewport height you can try. You can also raster your DOM on a canvas and then render the canvas image instead of HTML DOM on the screen.